# How to check if the markers in a google map are not behind any custom controls in the Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm using Google maps V3 API . I've added a custom control on the Map. Its having a width of 350px and height 300px.

Is there any way which i can figure out any of the marker is positioned behind the custom control on the Google maps.

Also i need to find out if i could able to find any marker is behind the custom control , i want it to change the position of the marker out of the custom control.